# Regex, given 2 expressions, select all sections in a multiline file that contains those 2 expressions and everything in between

Tags: regex

Given the sample text below, Im trying to generate a regex expression that will select the three sections in between the `set private-key` and the `-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"`, including the `set private-key` and the `-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"` lines.

I have the expression `^.*set private-key.*$` which selects the first section ok, and then I have `*^-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"$` which of course selects the ending section.  What I cant figure out is how to combine them to select the whole section.

I have tried `^.*set private-key.*$[\s\S]*^-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"$` but that ends up selecting everything between the first `set private-key` and the last `-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"` it finds, and everything in between it.  I want to select each section, so in the example below there would be 3 sections selected.

I have been fiddling with some regex labs on the net, but cannot seem to figure the solution to this puzzle, hence why Im here.

Thank you.

}Dan

```
    set comments "This is a comment "
    set private-key "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFHDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIpQqr96DiyZICAggA
MIIFHDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIpQqr96DiyZICAggA
MIIFHDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIpQqr96DiyZICAggA
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"

        set range global
        set source factory
        set last-updated 1546857127
    next
    edit "nothing important"
        set password ENC b1yM5KXgCoMcQ5Nc8zXW4RUgQe2XnxnVw3JDavLkx7L/dMwEudi2CuZDVEnqaoP/K3oKQb7r0WMwblzPu3sBzJkrSP28WQ==
        set comments "This is another comment"
        set private-key "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
JzW9TfmKu1lfYq/edslhke7RVPRpJ/Xu+Asbwd/P1qn/ffGbv713Xtyy95zBQbRe
8u1I3cGvr8LMHsMOdgFuHMr0OcVp7B9amCKQeXQImXK1SXHnZjPuIw7IYBlX1jvN
MIIFHDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIpQqr96DiyZICAggA
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"
    next
    edit "nothing important"
        set password ENC b1yM5KXgCoMcQ5Nc8zXW4RUgQe2XnxnVw3JDavLkx7L/dMwEudi2CuZDVEnqaoP/K3oKQb7r0WMwblzPu3sBzJkrSP28WQ==
        set comments "This is another comment"
        set private-key "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
JzW9TfmKu1lfYq/edslhke7RVPRpJ/Xu+Asbwd/P1qn/ffGbv713Xtyy95zBQbRe
8u1I3cGvr8LMHsMOdgFuHMr0OcVp7B9amCKQeXQImXK1SXHnZjPuIw7IYBlX1jvN
MIIFHDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIpQqr96DiyZICAggA
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"
    edit "nothing important"
        set password ENC b1yM5KXgCoMcQ5Nc8zXW4RUgQe2XnxnVw3JDavLkx7L/dMwEudi2CuZDVEnqaoP/K3oKQb7r0WMwblzPu3sBzJkrSP28WQ==
        set private-key "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAACmFlczI1Ni1jdHIAAAAGYmNyeXB0AAAAGAAAABDyqjjtjF
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAACmFlczI1Ni1jdHIAAAAGYmNyeXB0AAAAGAAAABDyqjjtjF
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAACmFlczI1Ni1jdHIAAAAGYmNyeXB0AAAAGAAAABDyqjjtjF
XUq7T96YiMJWNG4w==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
"
```

Comment: You just need to make your `[\s\S]*` non-greedy `[\s\S]*?`: [`^.*set private-key.*$[\s\S]*?^-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"$`](https://regex101.com/r/MYZYGR/1)

Comment: Really?!?  One single character.  LMAO!!  So close, and yet so far.  Thanks Hao!!  Make that an answer and I can mark it as such.

Comment: @DanSherwin, what language are you looking for? shell, awk, sed, perl kindly confirm once, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close! All you need to do is to make your `[\s\S]*` non-greedy `[\s\S]*?`. Thus it won't consume everything first and then combine multiple valid matches into one.

```
^.*set private-key.*$[\s\S]*?^-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"$
```

See the test cases here: https://regex101.com/r/MYZYGR/1